# Adding number of days to current date

Tags: php

I want to add some days to current date.I use following code for it.

```
$arrSearchValues=1000;

$datToDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+$arrSearchValues days"));
```

Everything working perfect until the number of days exceeds 9070.Above this number am getting result date "1970-01-01'". Is there any way to overcome this problem ?please help me with example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

January 19, 2038 is a special day: on that day, 32-bit date/time implementations based on [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) [run out of bits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) to represent dates and times, which is why the addition overflows and the result is reset to the start of the Unix epoch (Jan 1 1970).

To get around this restriction, switch to using [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and friends:

```
$d = new DateTime();
$d->modify("+10000 days");
echo $d->format("Y-m-d");
```

Comment: @Jon using DateTime is right but does'nt it modify the timestamp..I mean answer will be wrong .. will it not be good to show error instead?

Comment: Thangs jon.That works perfect for me

Comment: @new_developer: `DateTime` works fine, there is no error to show.

Answer (score 2):

As per http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 UTC to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC. (These are the dates that correspond to the minimum and maximum values for a 32-bit signed integer.)

after 9070 days your timestamp is getting out of range due to which you are not getting the valid timestamp and hence the error

You can show error if not valid timestamp

```
$arrSearchValues = 1000;
if(strtotime("+$arrSearchValues days"))
{
   $datToDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+$arrSearchValues days"));
}
else
{
    echo "Out of range";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should to be the fastest way:

```
$arrSearchValues=time()+1000*24*60*60;
$datToDate = date('Y-m-d', $arrSearchValues);
```

sorry, I forgot to use time(), check updated code.